# Print a percentage of all lines parsed in python

Tags: python

In a script, which reads lines from `stdin` or usually from a `tail -f`, the stdout is the print of these lines with a particular format, this is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin:
         print line
```

I need to print only a percentage these lines read, for example a random of 70% of them and discard the other 30%.

How can I print a random percentage (let's say 70%) of these lines?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: The first 70%? The last 70%? A random 70%?

Comment: The ramdom of the lines parsed

Comment: Since `tail -f` can keep growing... I'm not sure if that really makes any sense - you can't pick random items until it's finished, and you can't tell when it's finished...

Comment: @Jon, you could choose to print the current line 70% of the time.

Comment: Yes - of course you can - had one of those "blonde" moments ;(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if random.random() < 0.70:
            print line
```

This will print about 70% of the lines. The more lines you have, the closer it'll be to 70%.